# making ax excel ribbon that passes spread sheet columns to another program/API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

I am new to C# and VS. I am working on a problem in which I need to make an excel ribbon, that provides me with the functionality of passing column values in a sheet to another program that we have developed that does data visualization. I need some ideas on how to get started and how will it all work. For the same I needed some guidance. Any help on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Thanks.
Arun

Comment: What is the other program? Is it already running?  More details would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah the other program is an already developed visualization system that visualizes data as scatterplot, parallel coordinates etc. For the same I need to make a ribbon so that I can select particular columns from the excel sheet and pass it to that program which would then visualize the data. The visualization system is written in C# (not by me but my adviser). But in any case that can be extended if I know just how does data or message passing would work.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you'll have to make your visualization program able to start with one or two parameters. I would have the excel plugin save the selection to the temp folder in whichever format your visualization program uses, and do a process.start() on your visualization program, with an argument pointing at the just stored data. From there on your can read the stored data in the temp folder and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use copy and paste via the operating system clipboard?